# try/catch block inside the Spring rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it bad practice to have `try/catch` inside a controller in Spring? Or should I catch any errors inside the service and return it to the controller?
My example is:
`PlayerController`:

```
  @DeleteMapping("/api/players/{id}")
  ResponseEntity<String> deletePlayer(@PathVariable String id) {
     try {
       playerInterface.deletePlayer(Long.valueOf(id));
       return ResponseEntity.ok().body(String.format("Player with id: %s has been deleted", id));
     } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body("Could not delete a player");
        }
  }
```

and the `PlayerService`:

```
@Override
public void deletePlayer(Long id) {
  playerRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is nothing bad about handling the exception in the controller in such way, or should it be done EVERYWHERE like I did for the GET action using `ExceptionHandler`?

```
@ExceptionHandler(PlayerNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoPlayerFound(PlayerNotFoundException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(exception.getMessage());
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/api/players/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<Player> getPlayer(@PathVariable String id) {
        Player foundPlayer = playerInterface.getPlayer(Long.valueOf(id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(foundPlayer);
}
```

```
@Override
    public Player getPlayer(Long id) {
        Optional<Player> foundPlayer = playerRepository.findById(id);
        return foundPlayer.orElseThrow(PlayerNotFoundException::new);
}
```

I'd like just to know what's the standard that I should follow. I'm still new to Spring.

Comment: Whether we should catch an exception, and where we should catch it, depends entirely on the semantics of the exception, and what part of the application can handle it. The service layer may be able to handle some exceptions, but not others. I would advice to keep the controller layer as slim as possible, doing only protocol translations. If an exception should be propagatet to the client/response, I would advice to use [exception mappers (`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).

Answer (score -1):

The latest modern way as you mentioned is using the Optional Object and catch error with orElseThrow. This prevent to have a null point exception and consider the best practice.

```
@Override
public Player foundPlayerById(Long id) {
    Optional<Player> foundPlayer = playerRepository.findById(id);
    //prevent null point exception
    return foundPlayer.orElseThrow(PlayerNotFoundException::new);}
```

Comment: You cannot catch an error with `orElseThrow` that will throw an exception if nothing is found. This will also simply not work with a `delete` and only with a not-found. Also what is a best practice and what should be done depends entirly on the system being build.

Comment: why do you say I can't do it like this? Could you elaborate, because I don't understand?